# Unable to hit debugger in ( Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Dont what when wrong here , debuger use to hit the code. But after I delete the emulator and recreate one , after I cant debug the code.

I have to log exceptions using Log.e() which is quite painfully.

Can you please how to enable debuging ?

[image]

[image]

Breakpoints are enable, but they disable 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run --> Double click skip all breakpoints. Resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but from the picture it seems like all your breakpoints are disabled. Try enabling them (right click on breakpoint -> enable breakpoint)